# Read/Write access issue Python on Jupyter Server

Tags: python, pandas, file-permissions, jupyter

I am working on a Jupyter notebook server remotely and when I create a file using:

```
file = open("test.txt","w") file.write("test") file.close()
```

Everything works as expected and the file test.txt is written to the working directory. My problem arises wh trying to use the the Pandas to_hfs command:

```
data.to_hdf('raw_data.h5','raw_data_santodomingo',mode='w',format='f',data_columns=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
Opening raw_data.h5 in read-only mode
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in open(self, mode, **kwargs)
    586         try:
--> 587             self._handle = tables.open_file(self._path, self._mode, **kwargs)
    588         except (IOError) as e:  # pragma: no cover

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py in open_file(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    319     # Finally, create the File instance, and return it
--> 320     return File(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    321 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py in __init__(self, filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    783         # Now, it is time to initialize the File extension
--> 784         self._g_new(filename, mode, **params)
    785 

tables/hdf5extension.pyx in tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/utils.py in check_file_access(filename, mode)
    178                 raise IOError("directory ``%s`` exists but it can not be "
--> 179                               "written" % (parentname,))
    180     elif mode == 'a':

OSError: directory ``.`` exists but it can not be written

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-479f2e98ea81> in <module>()
----> 1 pre_clean_data.to_hdf('raw_data.h5','raw_data_santodomingo',mode='w',format='f',data_columns=True)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_hdf(self, path_or_buf, key, **kwargs)
   1136 
   1137         from pandas.io import pytables
-> 1138         return pytables.to_hdf(path_or_buf, key, self, **kwargs)
   1139 
   1140     def to_msgpack(self, path_or_buf=None, encoding='utf-8', **kwargs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in to_hdf(path_or_buf, key, value, mode, complevel, complib, append, **kwargs)
    267     if isinstance(path_or_buf, string_types):
    268         with HDFStore(path_or_buf, mode=mode, complevel=complevel,
--> 269                       complib=complib) as store:
    270             f(store)
    271     else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in __init__(self, path, mode, complevel, complib, fletcher32, **kwargs)
    446         self._fletcher32 = fletcher32
    447         self._filters = None
--> 448         self.open(mode=mode, **kwargs)
    449 
    450     @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in open(self, mode, **kwargs)
    589             if 'can not be written' in str(e):
    590                 print('Opening %s in read-only mode' % self._path)
--> 591                 self._handle = tables.open_file(self._path, 'r', **kwargs)
    592             else:
    593                 raise

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py in open_file(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    318 
    319     # Finally, create the File instance, and return it
--> 320     return File(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    321 
    322 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py in __init__(self, filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    782 
    783         # Now, it is time to initialize the File extension
--> 784         self._g_new(filename, mode, **params)
    785 
    786         # Check filters and set PyTables format version for new files.

tables/hdf5extension.pyx in tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/utils.py in check_file_access(filename, mode)
    154         # The file should be readable.
    155         if not os.access(filename, os.F_OK):
--> 156             raise IOError("``%s`` does not exist" % (filename,))
    157         if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    158             raise IOError("``%s`` is not a regular file" % (filename,))

OSError: ``raw_data.h5`` does not exist
```

These lines seem pertinent and are making me think write permission is the issue:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/utils.py in check_file_access(filename, mode)
    154         # The file should be readable.
    155         if not os.access(filename, os.F_OK):
--> 156             raise IOError("``%s`` does not exist" % (filename,))
    157         if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    158             raise IOError("``%s`` is not a regular file" % (filename,))
```

And

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/utils.py in check_file_access(filename, mode)
    154         # The file should be readable.
    155         if not os.access(filename, os.F_OK):
--> 156             raise IOError("``%s`` does not exist" % (filename,))
    157         if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    158             raise IOError("``%s`` is not a regular file" % (filename,))

OSError: ``raw_data.h5`` does not exist
```

However that would confuse me as I can write text files in the working directory as mentioned above. All and any attempts at assistance appreciated.

EDIT: If i use the full path :/home/joyvan/work/raw_data.h5' I get a different error readout.

```
data.to_hdf('/home/joyvan/work/raw_data.h5','raw_data_santodomingo',mode='w',format='f',data_columns=True)
```

produces

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-185-de493145e6a7> in <module>()
----> 1 pre_clean_data.to_hdf('/home/joyvan/work/raw_data.h5','raw_data_santodomingo',mode='w',format='f',data_columns=True)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_hdf(self, path_or_buf, key, **kwargs)
   1136 
   1137         from pandas.io import pytables
-> 1138         return pytables.to_hdf(path_or_buf, key, self, **kwargs)
   1139 
   1140     def to_msgpack(self, path_or_buf=None, encoding='utf-8', **kwargs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in to_hdf(path_or_buf, key, value, mode, complevel, complib, append, **kwargs)
    267     if isinstance(path_or_buf, string_types):
    268         with HDFStore(path_or_buf, mode=mode, complevel=complevel,
--> 269                       complib=complib) as store:
    270             f(store)
    271     else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in __init__(self, path, mode, complevel, complib, fletcher32, **kwargs)
    446         self._fletcher32 = fletcher32
    447         self._filters = None
--> 448         self.open(mode=mode, **kwargs)
    449 
    450     @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in open(self, mode, **kwargs)
    585 
    586         try:
--> 587             self._handle = tables.open_file(self._path, self._mode, **kwargs)
    588         except (IOError) as e:  # pragma: no cover
    589             if 'can not be written' in str(e):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py in open_file(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    318 
    319     # Finally, create the File instance, and return it
--> 320     return File(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    321 
    322 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py in __init__(self, filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    782 
    783         # Now, it is time to initialize the File extension
--> 784         self._g_new(filename, mode, **params)
    785 
    786         # Check filters and set PyTables format version for new files.

tables/hdf5extension.pyx in tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/utils.py in check_file_access(filename, mode)
    172                 parentname = '.'
    173             if not os.access(parentname, os.F_OK):
--> 174                 raise IOError("``%s`` does not exist" % (parentname,))
    175             if not os.path.isdir(parentname):
    176                 raise IOError("``%s`` is not a directory" % (parentname,))

OSError: ``/home/joyvan/work`` does not exist
```

Comment: I think the current directories "." in the two cases are different.
Use an absolute path to test (e.g. `/home/user/raw_data.h5` instead of `raw_data.h5`)

Comment: I have tried using a full path as demonstrated in the edit above, i get a different but similar error.

Comment: Does the folder /home/joyvan/work exist? Maybe just /home/joyvan exists?

Comment: yeah /home/joyvan/work exists and is the directory im working in, if i create a text file it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry for double-checking: does the folder /home/joyvan/work exists on the remote server where you are working or on your local machine? Do you know about any limitations on the server? Is this a public server? (Application may run chrooted so you don't have access to everything)
Can you also try with something like `/tmp/abc.h5` ?

Comment: The folder  /home/joyvan/work exists on the remote server. I can run a terminal in the server remotely through the Jupyter notebook interface in my browser on my local machine and see the work folder. I tried your suggestion and it seemed to work as it only threw a warning about perfomance issues related to data types. What is the significance of tmp/abc.h5 working?

Comment: I have solved the issue by using only the the name of the data file to save: 'raw_data.h5' , for example, an not writing a directory, this saved it in the ciurrent directory. Thanks for the assistance though Andrei

Answer (score 1):

- I ran into similar problem for this.
- It turns out that as a current user i am running file does not have enough permission to write.
- I ran same script with root user and it worked.

**Note:** This is late and not an answer to OP's Questions but similar situation for me and writing solution which worked for me.